# Deny steps with count more than 3 in osm2po

Tags: osm2po

wtr.tag.highway.steps =     1, 1, 1,   foot

In osm2po I can deny stairs with count 3 steps like this:

```
wtr.deny.step_count.3 = foot
```

But, I would like to prohibit stairs with a number of stages over 3 (so 4 and more).

```
wtr.deny.step_count.>3 = foot ---> that does not work in osm2po

wtr.allow.step_count.[1|2|3] = foot ---> that does not work in osm2po
```

Answer (score 1):

try `step_count` instead of `steps_count`

see: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Key:step_count

and dont forget to add the main-tag `wtr.tag.highway.steps` otherwise it wont be captured.
But be careful. The above will allow all steps and you'll have to reverse the expression. So simply set the steps to the flag `steps` instead of `foot`.

```
wtr.flagList = car, bike, foot, steps
wtr.finalMask = foot
...
wtr.tag.highway.steps = 1, 99, 3, steps
...
wtr.allow.step_count.[1|2|3] = foot
```

Comment: Hello Carsten, 
can you give me a code example for my problem?

Comment: example added to answer above